# Unable to integrate downloaded HTML template in wordpress Theme

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I am trying to Convert my HTML template into Wordpress template.But on browser it is only showing content without CSS. I refered the procedure from: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/converting-html-sites-to-wordpress-sites
here I added a below given statement on the top of a CSS file.I am confused about what to write in Theme URI and Author URI, as Right now I am workin on localhost server.

```
/*
Theme Name: ThemeIntegration
Theme URI: ??
Description: A brief description.
Version: 1.0
Author: You
Author URI: ??
*/
```

I am only getting Simple html content without styling.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add css and js files either in header or functions.php file, that tutorial is incomplete you can refer [this link](https://www.taniarascia.com/developing-a-wordpress-theme-from-scratch/)

If you have only 1 css then you can directly write it in style.css